# Calls to Node.js Socket.io on localhost not working, logging, emitting, creating errors, or doing anything else, but non-socket.io calls work fine

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I'm trying to make a real-time socket.io app in Angular and Node, exactly like what is explained [here](https://medium.com/@udara201/real-time-chat-application-with-socket-io-angular-and-nodejs-83f1a85d5024).  I set up the server and the client connection, but the connection is never made.

Server Code:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const host = process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.broadcast.emit('message-broadcast','Started');
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message-broadcast',msg);
    })
});
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port} + host ${host}`));
```

I had some issues with setting up the client code as it's explained in the tutorial.  When I used the line

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

and then tried to call

```
this.socket = io(environment.SocketEndpoint);
```

I received an error "This expression is not callable."
After some fiddling around I replaced the import line with

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
```

and the connect function with

```
  setupSocketConnection(){
    this.socket = io(environment.SocketEndpoint).connect();
    
    this.socket.on('message-broadcast', (data: string)=>{
      console.log('Recieved message:',data);
    })
    console.log('Set up socket',this.socket);
  }
```

This MIGHT be related to the issue, but I don't think it is.
When I do this, it APPEARS to work, in the sense that I can see periodic calls in the Networking tab, which look like

```
http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbRCamo
```

But none of these calls do anything.  They show up red in the Networking tab.  The timing tab says they are "stalled".  On the server, there is no console log associated with these calls, nor does the client receive any kind of emitted message.

What's odd is that I CAN get a response by pasting this call in the browser, which looks like this:

```
0{"sid":"3KsDDAa1mA2OVxKIAADT","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}
```

But there is still no console logging on the server.  In fact any call that starts with "server.io" doesn't create any logging at all. But if I make *any* other call to the server that *doesn't* start with "socket.io", I DO get a console log recording that the call was made - even if it's only a 404 error.  So I know that socket.io must be doing SOMETHING, it just isn't doing what it's supposed to.

EDIT: Okay, when I uploaded it to a different server it seems to work all right - it's only a problem with localhost, apparently.  I guess I could manage, but being able to test on localhost would be convenient, so if anyone can figure this out it would be helpful.

EDIT2: It was caused by a CORS policy issue.  I was able to fix it by changing the server code to this:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const host = process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:4200",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.broadcast.emit('message-broadcast','Started');
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message-broadcast',msg);
    })
});
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port} + host ${host}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to CORS problems. I had a similar issue where i had the socketio server running on port 5000, the angular app on 4200, which the CORS policy did not like at all. I solved this using a proxy configuration and starting the dev server with `--proxy-config proxy.json`.

proxy.json:

```
{
 "/socket.io": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "ws": true,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": { }
    }
}
```

Not sure if it's the same issue for you though.

Comment: Didn't do anything different.  Considering that the logging problem also exists when inputting the request into a browser, I'm guessing that changing the client won't help.

Comment: After more fiddling, I was able to fix it by adding a CORS policy to the server.  So this answer was on the right track.

Comment: @IndigoFenix oh that might be because you set your server to listen to `http://127.0.0.1`, but you call `http://localhost`. Semantically, that's the same, but it might end up with different `Host` header values.